# When using an OracleCommand in .net must the OracleClient be installed on the machine or does .net cover this?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I want to make a simple query on an Oracle database from .net using similar code to this.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

class Sample
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Connect to Oracle
        string constr = "User Id=scott;Password=tiger;Data Source=AKI1.WORLD";
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
        con.Open();

        // Display Version Number
        Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle " + con.ServerVersion);

        // Read REF CURSOR into DataSet
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "GetComplexTabPkg.GetEmp";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_dep", OracleDbType.Int16).Value = 20;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("p_ref", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction
             = ParameterDirection.Output;

        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.TableMappings.Add("Emp", "Emp");
        da.Fill(ds);

        // Close and Dispose OracleConnection
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();

        // Show Message
        Console.WriteLine("DataSet filled");
    }
}
```

My only concern is does the Oracle Client need to be installed on the web server that is running this code? It's my first time using this and I would like to avoid any obvious issues that can be prevented. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Oracle Client need to be installed in web server. The work around will be to ship your application with [Instant Oracle Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html)

Answer (score 0):

On my Own I just install [64-bit Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC)](http://www.oracle.com/us/products/tools/index-090165.html) Downloads, which seems to be lighter than Oracle Client.